# Why does the absence of diabatic heating rate and frictional terms make the zonal and vertical velocity identically zero?

Tags: atmosphere, tropical-cyclone, mesoscale-meteorology

I was reading an article on fluid dynamics of tropical cyclones, where I came across a condition which states that,

> For adiabatic friction less flow, equations (1) to (5) have a
>   solution, v(r, z), for a steady freely spinning vortex in which u and
>   w are identically zero and v(r, z) is an arbitrary function of r and
>   z.

Where these 5 equations are basic primitive equations (2 horizontal and 1 vertical equation of motion,conservation of mass and thermodynamic equation) written in cylindrical coordinates.

If I try to consider the horizontal(u component only) and vertical equations of motion when they are in gradient wind and hydrostatic balance, u and w will be conserved i.e du/dt=0 and dw/dt=0.
How can one conclude that they are identically zero?
For the article, please open the following link 
https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.meteo.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~roger/Publications/M17.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjvzPOsmOzYAhUeSo8KHf3wC5YQFjAEegQIDRAB&usg=AOvVaw3uxV6Wyli4JcGq3qrQzR00

The primitive equations are given in section 2.1 and the lines highlighted above are taken from the first paragraph of section 2.2

Comment: Please, cite your source. Context matters. For example, are you sure that those u,v,w are not formulated in a locally co-rotating frame?

Comment: Please open  the following link https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.meteo.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~roger/Publications/M17.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjvzPOsmOzYAhUeSo8KHf3wC5YQFjAEegQIDRAB&usg=AOvVaw3uxV6Wyli4JcGq3qrQzR00

Comment: Please learn to cite properly. I'm not gonna read a 24 page paper for this. Cite page, section and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The authors are not very explicit about it, but the section title clearly says "The equations in cylindrical polar coordinates." Thus I'd assume $u,v,w$ have meaning in the cyclone-centered coordinate system, not in the planetary one. Therefore $\dot{u} = 0$, as per definition of a cyclone in this coordinate system.

Comment: Yes, but that does not say that u is zero identically. Zero derivative doesn't imply that the function is also zero. Please make it clear.

Comment: They say they're using a 'steady, freely spinning vortex' so they're already plugging in u and w as zero as initial conditions. Then by requirement u and w stay that way. Plugging that into the equations and checking, shows that there is no contradiction, so $u=w=0$ can be (part of) the solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am still learning so understanding everything at my own pace. By the way why did I get my question downvoted?

Comment: No problem. I'm not 100% sure about this, but this is how i'd read it. Taking a look at the reference they give might help as well. The downvote's not me this time!